# LightDM Black screen on boot

Tags: boot, lightdm

I am upgrading from 19.10 to 20.04 and I get a blackscreen on boot.
In the past this has been a driver issue and I can clearly see the Segfaults or Kernel panics in the logs.
This time I don't know how to debug it.  The dmesg and journalctl logs (are they the same log?) seem fine.  I can get to the console via `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F2` so I can debug a bit.

[Gist of the logs](https://gist.github.com/Chocrates/bdf2aba2df7cd10793af9e8e3b42cbe4)

Steps to debug:

1. Install all updates
2. `sudo apt install --reinstall lightdm`
3. `sudo systemctl restart lightdm`
4. It jumps me to tty 7 (I assume) and its a black screen, though my monitor doesn't turn off
5. Repeat the above steps with `gdm3`  this results in `gdm` starting in tty2 and doesn't seem to have an effect

Of note, I have a dedicated graphics card and an integrated graphics chip, plugging my monitor into either nets the same results.
Any idea how I can debug this further?  I can update the gist with any details necessary.

Comment: Does comment #6 here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1757091 provide any useful information?

Comment: Do you have any greeter installed, like 'lightdm-gtk-greeter' or 'lightdm-webkit-greeter'?

Comment: Do you have more thhan one DE installed? Type `ls /usr/bin/*session` and can you confirm that your current one is in fact lightdm? Type `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`

Comment: Hey All,  I ended up removing `lightdm`, `gdm3`, and `ubuntu-desktop` and reinstalling the latter.  That got the machine to boot to a desktop but the mouse was missing.  I then tried a wayland session and that seemed to work.  I think the tl;dr is that I need to back my data up and format the drive unfortunately.